# String is converted to Array on URL opencart link

Tags: php, html, opencart2.x

I have some code in the category.php of opencart to interact with my module, i need to pass an array as string to the URL but i'm missing something, it appears that opencart has a function that keeps converting the string to array again...

here is my code

```php
//MOD EOT - Adicionar os campos dos Filtros
if (isset($this->request->get['eot_filter'])) { 
    $eot_filters_url = $this->request->get['eot_filter'];               
    //$final_url = '';
    foreach ($eot_filters_url as $key=>$filter) {
        $final_url = '&eot_filter['.$key.'][Attr_id]='. $filter['Attr_id'];
        $final_url.= '&eot_filter['.$key.'][text]='.  $filter['text'];  

        $url .= $final_url;

    }
}
//MOD EOT END - Adicionar os campos dos Filtros

$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->total = $product_total;
$pagination->page = $page;
$pagination->limit = $limit;
$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');
```

the `$pagination->url` puts `&eot_filter=array` instead of `&eot_filter[0][Attr_id]=...`

Comment: Might want `http_build_query()` instead

Comment: already tried but don't remember the result, i will check it again

Comment: can you do a print_r of  $eot_filters_url  ?

Comment: Yes, i can, it gives me `Array ( [0] => Array ( [Attr_id] => 58 [text] => Homem ) ) `

Comment: Where and how did you initialise `$url`?

Comment: $url in initialised by the core of opencart...
` $url = ''; `

Comment: Let's try to catch the content of the `$url` variable before it is converted. Add a `file_put_contents('filter.txt`, $url);` where your comment `//MOD EOT END` is shown, call the page and check the contents of the file "filter.txt" that has been created.

Comment: @SaschaM78 already did that here is the result `%26eot_filter%5B0%5D%5BAttr_id%5D%3D59%26eot_filter%5B0%5D%5Btext%5D%3DAnel` because i put the $finalurl  inside urlencode...

without the urlencode it givesme what i want `&eot_filter[0][Attr_id]=59&eot_filter[0][text]=Anel`

Comment: I assume it's the helper function `$this->url->link()` that interferes with your URL. Either try `http_build_query()` as mentioned by @Qirel or don't use `$this->url->link()` and build the link yourself.

Comment: is it possible with the http_build_query pass the array in the URL like this `eot_filter[0][Attr_id]=1` instead of this `0[Attr_id]=1`